# How to use XTK read arrayBuffer data

Tags: dicom, arraybuffer, xtk

I would like to know how to read arrayBuffer data (DICOM arrayBuffer) by using XTK library. I have already tried lots methods, but do not work.

Comment: According to the documentation, only uncompressed DICOMs are supported. Do you have proper files?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/73av5041/3/

shows that volume.file can be a array of name files. Then put the `arrayBuffer` data into `volume.filedata` directly. Keep the number of files and the length of `arrayBuffer` same.